# why the size of stored index changed dramatically?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding, indices

There is a `company` index, today I found a strange phenomenon, that is the doc count does not change but the `size of stored index` is changed dramatically from 22.03GB to 27.14GB then instantly becomes 20.44GB. Why is so? What are done in the elasticsearch internal?

[image]

More metrics

[image]

[image]

It seems the segment count and size both reduced, Did these metrics could explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Three questions: (1) did this ever happened before? (2) was the number of nodes in the cluster stable in that time window? (3) Have you changed the number of replicas?

Comment: @glenacota answer: 1. No 2. Yes Actually just one machine  3. No

Comment: Do you have a lot of updates happening? My guess would be a [merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html), which cleans up replaced or deleted documents.

Comment: @xeraa I added more metrics, can these metrics could explain the phenomenon?

Comment: Yes, the segment count reducing means there was a merge — segment cound and size are a clear indicator. This works as expected; it's a bit like a garbage collection.